# Mockito - ClassCastException when using Collection

Tags: generics, mockito

I have a puzzling problem when mocking a class with a method that gets a collection as an argument.

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo () { }

    public boolean doSomething(List<Bar> bars) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar() {}
}
```

When trying to create a mock

```
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
```

I get:

```
Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
If you are not sure...

Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastExcception@1ba9917e
...
```

Sorry for the short error description, I had to copy by hand from offline terminal.

When I change the argument of the `doSomething()` method to just `doSomething(Bar bar)` it succeeds in creating the mock.

One final weird thing, it doesn't reproduce on other workstations.

Comment: Well, `do` is a keyword in Java (`do while` loop). I wouldn't be surprised if naming method with a keyword would cause some weird errors.

Comment: My mistake, @peter, I meant to write some generic function name. I typed directly without compiler because I can't paste the code..updated

Comment: @Sagi: You have notified the wrong user, it seems.

Comment: "Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes" that's the problem (in your "real" code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, the only difference between the machines was the JDK version. On the machine where it wasn't working we had 1.8.0_05. Updating to 1.8.0_45 fixed it.